# Knockout js $index() doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the below code to print the id for the div. But $index() doesnt seem to work,

```
<div data-bind="foreach: itemRows">
           <div class="fruitList" data-bind="foreach: $data">
                <div data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'uniqueName_' + $index() }">
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data }" />
                 </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Any suggestion..

Update:
  The rendered HTML has this

```
<div id="uniqueName_NaN" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'uniqueName_' + ($parent.index +   

  $data.index) }">
```

Id is not showing up.. Am i missing something..

Comment: Your id generating code should work fine with: `data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'uniqueName_' + $index() }"` http://jsfiddle.net/naXbe/ . You have your problem some where

Comment: Your rendered HTML doesn't match your original in the `data-bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just $index, so without the ()

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: itemRows">
       <div class="fruitList" data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <div data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'uniqueName_' + $index }">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data }" />
             </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since your in a nested foreach, you might need the index of the parent. Try using **'uniqueName_' + $parent.index + '_' + $data.index**

Comment: i am not able to see the id in the html

Comment: `<div data-bind="attr: { id': 'uniqueName_' + $data.index }">` i tried this as well  and now the rendered div doesnt have an id attr only

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? You'r missing a quote in the id key in your comment.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `$index` is an observable and so must be accessed using the function syntax. If you want to get the index from the outer loop, it will be `$parentContext.$index()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the index from both loops, you need to access the parent context. The index is stored in the context object, not in `$data`.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: itemRows">
    <div class="fruitList" data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <div data-bind="attr: { 'id': 
                'uniqueName_' + $parentContext.$index() + '_' + $index() }">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data }" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```